# Passport-jwt authenticate not working well with node-jwt-simple

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, koa, passport.js

I'm using `passport-jwt` to authenticate some routes and I'm creating my `jwt`s with `node-jwt-simple`/`jwt-simple` but facing some difficulties cause it looks like my `passport-jwt` authenticate middleware is not being called at all.

Here is my

**passport-jwt-strategy**

```js
const jwtOpts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('Authorization'),
    secretOrKey: secret,
};

passport.use(new jwtStrategy(jwtOpts, (payload, done) => {

    console.log('payload ', payload.sub);
    User.findById(payload.sub, (err, user) => {
        
        if(err) { return done(err); }

        if(!user) { console.log('didnt find!'); return done(null, false); }

        done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

which i'm then integrating it over here.

**routes file**

```js
router.get('/success', 
           passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}),
           async (ctx, next) => ctx.body = await "success!");
```

Here is also the way I make my `jwt`.

```js
function tokenForUser(user) {
    
    const timeStamp = new Date().getTime;
    return jwt.encode({sub: user._id, iat: timeStamp}, secret);
}

//- Later in signup process

userToSave.save(async(err, user) => {
    
    if(err) { return next(err); }

    const token = await tokenForUser(user);

    next(token);
});


//- If this helps, here is how my secret file looks like.

const secret = "JKAha23ja1ddHdjjf31";

export default secret;
```

Problem comes, when I hit that route i only get `Unauthorized` and in the console nothing gets logged out *not even the 'payload' key I specified first*.

I should also say that I have the token at `ctx.request.get('Authorization')` (Koa based) i think it's something like `req.header('Authorization')` with express in all routes.

Also **The exact express based problem** can be found on the github issues of `node-jwt-simple` [here](https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple/issues/54) incase there is any problem with my code samples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I wrapped my head right i knew that this has been my horrible understanding of how the whole authentification process works.

When I decoded the token from `ctx.get('Authorization')` I got a different `_id` than the one stored in the db **Because** I had hardcoded **Authorization** header in postman and thought *"If I `ctx.set('Authorization', token);` It will replace the one I hardcoded on postman".*

Less did I think that this `jwt` will be included in a header of requests when I make http calls on front end.

I naively thought `jwt`s are passed directly from the server to the browser (Something like how `render` works) and **Not** from the server to an `ajax` process which later embeds it in request made which is the correct way.

The whole code is awesome, except now I have to just pass the token `ctx.body = token;` after I created it when I signed up.

Thank You.